# ListRowPresenter Disabling Shadow disables overlap of view

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have disabled shadow effect in List Row Presenter in browse fragment.

Now because of that in default animation of selected item does not overlap on next item it comes behind it.

How to overcome this, any idea ?

Lines of Code..

```
ListRowPresenter l = new ListRowPresenter;
l.setShadowEnabled(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're right, I think you need to override z-ordering. Can you disable z-ordering when you disable shadow effect and try again -

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.html#isUsingZOrder(android.content.Context)

Comment: There's a bug in Leanback library which isn't respecting the z-ordering when shadow is disabled. We've made the fix, it will be available in 24.2.1 release. Thanks for reporting this issue.